# Literature for the Bichteler-Dellacherie Semimartingale characterization.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis

For my master thesis I have to show that a fractional brownian motion is not a semimartingale. So I searched for an easy way to show this and come to the following statement for semimartingales
Let  $K_S^n=\sum_{k=1}^{k_n}\alpha_k^n \mathbb{1}_{(t_{k-1},t_k]}(s)$  be a simple predictable process, $\alpha^n_k \in F_{t_{k−1}}$ and $0=t_0<t_1\cdots<t_{k_n}=T$. A stochastic process is an semimartingale if and only if for any sequence of predictable simple processes $k_n$ with the property $\sup_{s≤T}|K^n_s|\to0$ in probability we also have
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{k_n}\alpha_k^n(X_{t_k}-X_{t_{k-1}})\to 0$$ in probability.
This statment was mentioned here [Why is a fractional Brownian motion not a semi-martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963646/why-is-a-fractional-brownian-motion-not-a-semi-martingale)

My problem is that I dont find any source for this theorem. Does anybody knows a book or a valid source where the statement is formulated specific and is equipped with a proof?

Thanks.

Comment: You might be interested in George Lowther's blog "almost sure" https://almostsure.wordpress.com/