# Fractional Brownian Motion is not a semimartingale

Tags: stochastic-processes, normal-distribution, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

In some sources (for example here: [Why is a fractional Brownian motion not a semi-martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963646/why-is-a-fractional-brownian-motion-not-a-semi-martingale)) you can find a proof why the fractional Brownian motion is not a semimartingale via the Bichteler-Dellacherie theorem.

There are two things I do not understand.

- Firstly, the simple predictable processes $K^n$ are used with
  $$
  K^n:=\sum_{j=1}^n n^{2H-1} \left(B^H_{\frac{jT}{n}}-B^H_{\frac{(j-1)T}{n}}\right)1_{\left[ \frac{jT}{n}, \frac{(j+1)T}{n}\right]}.
  $$
- Secondly, it is mentioned that according to the Bichteler-Dellacherie Theorem a process $X$ is a semimartingale if and only if for any sequence of predictable simple processes $K^n$ with the property $\displaystyle\sup_{s≤T}|K^n_s|$ converge in probability to 0.

My understanding is:

- These processes are not simple predictable processes as they are not bounded.
- The Bichteler-Dellacherie theorem requires the essential supremum of simple processes converge to 0 and not the supremum in probability.

Is my understanding correct and, if yes, can we somehow still use this argument to prove that the fractional Brownian motion is not a semimartingale?
For example, would it work to define a sequence like $H^{n,m}:=K^n\wedge \frac 1m$ for which you can choose an appropriate diagonal sequence which converges to 0 but the integral wrt the fractional Brownian motion does not?

Comment: Going through Bichteler-Dellacherie is not my favourite proof of the fact fBM is not a semimartingale. It's easier to prove this by studying the $p$-th variation of the process.

Answer (score 1):

**Using p-variation**

First for a short proof. We follow [Arbitrage with fractional Brownian motion](http://www.long-memory.com/fractional-brownian-motion/Rogers1997.pdf). The key is that a [semimartingale always has finite quadratic variation](https://planetmath.org/quadraticvariationofasemimartingale), and if its quadratic variation is zero, then it is of bounded variation.

Consider the interval $[0,1]$ on which is defined the fractional Brownian motion $B_{H}$, and consider its partitions $\pi_n = \{t^n_k = \frac{k}{2^{n}} : 0\le 1\le 2^{n}\},\ n\in\mathbb N$ and

$$ V_p^{n}(B_{H}) =  \sum_{k=1}^{2^{n}} |B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k)|^p. $$

By the [ergodic theorem applied to fBM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/261730/applying-ergodic-theorem-on-fractional-brownian-motion?rq=1)

$$\frac{V_p^{n}(B_{H})}{2^{n(1-pH)}}\to E[|B_{H}(1)-B_{H}(0)|^{p}]=c_{p}\neq 0.$$

Therefore,
$$ V_p(B_{H}) =\begin{cases}
        \infty, & \text{if }\ pH < 1, \\
        0,       & \text{if }\ pH > 1.
    \end{cases}
$$

If $H<\frac{1}{2}$, we get $V_{2}(B_{H})=+\infty$. If $H>\frac{1}{2}$, then we get that $V_{2}(B_{H})=0$ and $V_{1}(B_{H})=+\infty$ but this contradicts that if a semimartingale has zero quadratic variation, it least has finite 1-variation.

**Using The Bichteler-Dellacherie Theorem**

From [The Bichteler-Dellacherie Theorem](https://almostsuremath.com/2011/03/28/the-bichteler-dellacherie-theorem/#scn_bdt_eq1) and [Existence of the Stochastic Integral](https://almostsuremath.com/2010/03/03/existence-of-the-stochastic-integral/) we use the definition/theorem

Theorem 1 A cadlag adapted process X is a semimartingale if and only if, for each {t\ge 0}, the set

$$\displaystyle  \left\{\int_0^t\xi\,dX\colon \xi{\rm\ is\ elementary}, \vert\xi\vert\le 1\right\}  (3)$$

is bounded in probability. This is equivalent to the statement that, for any sequence ${\xi^n}$ of bounded predictable processes converging uniformly to zero, ${\int_0^t\xi^n\,dX} $ converges to zero in probability.

As mentioned in [Why is a fractional Brownian motion not a semi-martingale?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963646/why-is-a-fractional-brownian-motion-not-a-semi-martingale), it suffices to take

$$\xi^{n}(t):=\sum^{2^{n}}_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{n(1-2H)}}(B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k))1_{(t^n_{k},t^n_{k+1}]}(t)$$

because then by [Hölder continuity of fBM](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257904/h%C3%B6lder-continuity-of-fractional-brownian-motion#:%7E:text=The%20fractional%20Brownian%20motion%20B,t%E2%88%92s%7C%CE%B1H.) we have $|B_{(k+1)/2^{n}}-B_{(k)/2^{n}}|\leq c/2^{n(H-\epsilon)}$ and so

$$\sup_{t\leq 1}|1_{|\xi^{n}(t)|\leq 1}\xi^{n}(t)|\leq \frac{c}{2^{n(1-H-\epsilon)}}\to 0,$$
for small $\epsilon>0$ and random constant $c$. On the other hand,

$$\int 1_{|\xi^{n}(t)|\leq 1}\xi^{n}(t)dB_{H}(t)=\frac{V_2^{n}(B_{H})}{2^{n(1-2H)}}-\int 1_{|\xi^{n}(t)|\geq 1}\xi^{n}(t)dB_{H}(t).$$

We already have $\frac{V_2^{n}(B_{H})}{2^{n(1-2H)}}\to c_{2}\neq 0.$ We also have

$$\int 1_{|\xi^{n}(t)|\geq 1}\xi^{n}(t)dB_{H}(t)\approx \sum^{2^{n}}_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{n(1-2H)}}(B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k))^{2}1\{|\frac{1}{2^{n(1-2H)}}(B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k))|\geq 1\}$$

$$\leq1\{\frac{c}{2^{n(1-H-\epsilon)}}\geq 1\}\sum^{2^{n}}_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{n(1-2H)}}(B_{H}(t^n_{k+1})-B_{H}(t^n_k))^{2}.$$

Here we can apply Cauchy-Schwartz to bound by $P[\frac{c}{2^{n(1-H-\epsilon)}}\geq 1](E[(\frac{V_2^{n}(B_{H})}{2^{n(1-2H)}})^{2}])^{1/2}$. The ergodic theorem also works for $L_{p},p>1$ convergence to turn the second factor into $c_{2}$ again. For the first factor, we use that the Hölder-norm has finite moments see "Kolmogorov-Chentsov" in Schilling

$$E[c^{\alpha}]=E[\sup\frac{|\xi(x)-\xi(y)|^{\alpha}}{|x-y|^{\alpha\gamma}}]<\infty$$

and hence $P[\frac{c}{2^{n(1-H-\epsilon)}}\geq 1]\to 0$.

Comment: How are you getting the bound on $\xi^n$? Looks to me like the increments of fBM are unbounded

Comment: The increment $B_t^H - B_s^H$ is Gaussian, hence unbounded. Or did you require a different sense of boundedness here?

Comment: I updated by replacing with $1_{|\xi^{n}(t)|\leq 1}\xi^{n}(t)$.